# R Line Graph Deformed After Manually Adding Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I've attempted to manually add a legend to a simple line graph, however after making the changes to insert the legend the actual lines in the graph have become deformed and I don't know what's causing this issue.

Original Code:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = var1), colour = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = var2), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = var3), color = "green") +
  geom_line(aes(y = var4), colour = "black")
```

Modified Code for Adding Legend:

```
df_sub <- df[,c(1, 2,3,4, 5)]
dd = melt(df_sub, id=c("Time"))
ggplot(dd) + geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=value, colour=variable, group = 1 ))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","green","blue", "black"))
```

Graph: 
[image]

Comment: `group = 1` should be `group = variable`, I think (or not included at all). `group = 1` tells ggplot to treat all data as part of the same line.

Comment: @Marius Cheers that fixed the issue